# Javascript for Google Chrome detecting & Enable javascript in Google Chrome

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax, cross-browser

My application's JavaScript is working on Firefox and IE but it is not working in Google Chrome. Is it problem of enable javascript in Google chrome? or I must put any code in javascript for getting XMLHttpRequest Object of Google chrome browser.

Comment: Can you give us an example of something that's not working?  What about a simple alert() ?

Comment: yes, I call one function of javascript when <input type="text" id="txt_acname1" runat="server" style="height:18px;Width:118px;" maxlength="30" onblur="ajaxFunction(this.value)" /> It will not give one alert which is given in that at the starting of this function. please help me.

Comment: I got two errors in that Like Sys is not define Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initial... document.getElementById('aspnetForm'));
and Sys.Application.initialize();

Answer (score 1):

If the code works in two other browsers but not in Chrome, you need to look at  the code for your "ajaxFunction" because that is apparently what is giving Chrome a headache. As @Artem mentioned, Ctrl+Shift+J will bring up the Javascript Console (switch it to the "Scripts" tab) and you can easily examine any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome's Javascript engine interprets JS very similarly to the other browsers mentioned. What is it that doesn't appear to be working?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Javascript Console in Chrome, press Ctrl+Shift+J to open it and check for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508994/asp-net-dropdownlist-autopostback-and-google-chrome) related to this problem? Problem could be that .NET thinks you're using the Safari Browser instead of Chrome...