# Listbox not causing post back in Chrome and Safari

Tags: asp.net, listbox

In chrome and safari I am having problems with a list box I have. The data is loaded on the backend initially which works fine. But then on the event SelectedIndexChange I want to figure out what they selected and update my panel with that info. Problem is chrome and safari is not calling the event. Ive checked for script erros and get none. IE and FF work just fine, so I am just wondering what is wrong with those browsers and what I can do to fix this. Basically this is a control that sits inside a sharepoint 2007 page.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="ISudpl" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<strong>Product</strong><br /><asp:ListBox  runat="server" ID="Product" 
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="Filter_SelectedIndexChanged" EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true" 
                SelectionMode="Multiple" Rows="15" CssClass="designIntent"/>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Product" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the Chrome JavaScript Console? Any errors show up there when changing your selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a documented issue with Microsoft AJAX and webkit based browsers check here http://blog.turlov.com/2009/01/aspnet-ajax-compatibility-patch-for.html and here [Asp.Net, DropDownList, AutoPostBack and Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508994/asp-net-dropdownlist-autopostback-and-google-chrome) for a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

You do not need Trigger because your control(ListBox) is inside same UpdatePanel. Please remove the complete `<Triggers></Triggers>` block from your code and check if it works in Chrome?